# Permit arbitrary number of integers with strong_params

Tags: ruby-on-rails, security, parameters

I'm thinking perhaps an array is the way to go, but I'm not sure how to only allow arrays of integers. Here's what I'm starting with:

```
def put_params
  params.require(:project).permit(technologies: [])[:technologies]
end
```

I want to be able to accept an arbitrary number of technology IDs securely.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As long as the `technologies` param is passed as an array, you just need to use

```
def put_params
  params.require(:project).permit(:technologies)
end
```

The fundamental part, here, is how you pass the parameter. You need to make sure the parameter is passed as Array. You can read more in the [official documentation](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_controller_overview.html#hash-and-array-parameters).

> The params hash is not limited to one-dimensional keys and values. It can contain arrays and (nested) hashes. To send an array of values, append an empty pair of square brackets "[]" to the key name:
>
> ```
> GET /clients?ids[]=1&ids[]=2&ids[]=3
> ```
>
> The actual URL in this example will be encoded as "/clients?ids%5b%5d=1&ids%5b%5d=2&ids%5b%5d=3" as "[" and "]" are not allowed in URLs. Most of the time you don't have to worry about this because the browser will take care of it for you, and Rails will decode it back when it receives it, but if you ever find yourself having to send those requests to the server manually you have to keep this in mind.
>
> The value of params[:ids] will now be ["1", "2", "3"]. Note that parameter values are always strings; Rails makes no attempt to guess or cast the type.